# In what bases is $101$ the only prime in the sequence $1,101,10101,\ldots$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, prime-numbers

$101$ is the only prime in the sequence $1,101,10101,\ldots$ as shown [in this Putnam question](https://mks.mff.cuni.cz/kalva/putnam/psoln/psol891.html).

I also know from studying the Collatz conjecture that $101_2$ is also the only prime in the same sequence considered as a sequence of base $2$ numbers.

In what bases is this true, and is there a general proof for some class of bases?

Comment: There is currently no known general solution to your question. This is since it's solution requires knowledge of primes of the form $101_n=n^2+1$. If the bases can be written $n=2^{2^{k-1}}$, then $2^{2^k}+1$ must be prime. This is called a Fermat prime, and it is currently unknown for what of values of $k$ this number becomes prime, and also if there are finitely/infinitely many of them. See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat_number for more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proof in the Putnam question goes through regardless of the base.  Replace $10$ by $b$, $9$ by $b-1$ and $11$ by $b+1$. It is true in all bases $b$ where $b^2+1$ is prime.